# How Many Times A File's Been Opened

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to tell how many times a file's been opened without any external software? (I.e., using only C# and/or any libraries)?

That is, is there a way for me to install a C# app, and only that app, on a new computer and see the activity on each file in the system?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:
I'm not looking to intercept the opening of a file, I was more wondering if Windows keeps a log of the number of times a file's been accessed in it's history, or something along those lines (without any external software).

Comment: Yes. And your app would then probably be called an antivirus.

Comment: Alternative to duplicate - use FS audit: main part of this question about enabling FS audit on given OS (I.e. Windows - [Plan for File Access Auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831382.aspx) ) is off-topic on SO and should be asked on http://serverfault.com . For "C# app" part you'd need to add more information what you tried/not work to be good SO question.

Comment: I can't use FS audit, as this would be installed on it's own on a computer. I haven't tried anything yet because I have no idea where to start.